# What happens to Airflow Sensor running on Celery worker if worker itself goes down

Tags: airflow

Use Case:
DAG has a Rest API task defined (using RestOperator) which hits application api and starts execution of a process/task which does some business function. It's execution status is monitored with Airflow Sensor which poll for task execution completion status via an API call.

Question:

1. If a Celery node goes down, What will happen to Sensor which was running on that node.
2. if Sensor dies with worker, How to propagate sensor execution to another node (to avoid loss of functionality).

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.providers.http.sensors.http import HttpSensor
from airflow.providers.http import SimpleHttpOperator

default_args = {
    'start_date': datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
    'end_date': None
}

dag = DAG(
    'Rest Monitor',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None,
    catchup=False)

HttpOperator = SimpleHttpOperator(
    task_id='RestOperator',
    method='POST',
    endpoint='https://localhost:8080/api/task/execute',
    headers={
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    data={
        "taskId": "1234",
    }
},
dag = dag )

def resp_check():
    return "True if Status = Success"

HttpSensor = HttpSensor(
    dag = dag,
    task_id = 'http_sensor_head_method',
    http_conn_id = 'http_default',
    endpoint = 'https://localhost:8080/api/task/1234/status',
    request_params = {},
    method = 'HEAD',
    response_check = resp_check,
    timeout = 5,
    poke_interval = 1)


HttpOperator >> HttpSensor
```

Comment: Is there a state maintained during the execution of the sensor, perhaps some sort of identifier to correlate back to the request? Could you share some code?

Comment: Added code, it's just scratch code to give insight of what I want to achieve

Comment: Awesome, that makes a lot more sense. Is the `taskId` value dynamic or fixed per DAG?

Comment: it's dynamic, I haven't put the xcom code here just for simplicity. In actual scenario it will come from RestOperator through xcom

Comment: Gotcha, so it's basically an identifier, generated by the HTTP server, to correlate an (_I'm assuming asynchronous?_) request status, that you've setup to share through the XCom?

Comment: Yes, It will hit an API (using this identifier of task) and task will do some processing and return execution status (success/failed) which sensor will wait to mark schedule status. Similar to this AIPhttps://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-28%3A+Add+AsyncExecutor+option

Answer (score 0):

This logic is ostensibly managed by Airflow core and its coordination of workers via the `Scheduler`. Basically, the scheduler polls or is sent Task state / log data from the worker node at regular intervals.

Essentially the Scheduler manages data coming from the work about the worker explicitly and about the Task the worker is supposed to be managing. If either the worker becomes non-responsive or not enough data is being returned about the task. The Scheduler will begin it shutdown  task and fail try logic.

If there are more retries for the Task, then a new copy of the task will be added to the queue for any live workers in your cluster to pick up.